# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x\frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n^2}$. My try.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Examine the convergence of:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x\frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n^2}$$

---

Pointwise convergence (for every $ x \in \mathbb{R}$ ):

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x\frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n^2} = 0$ , because $\sin(n^2x) \in [-1, 1]$

---

Uniform convergence (for every $ x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ):

form dirichlet criterion:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x\frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n^2} = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x) \cdot g_n(x) $$ where:

- $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n} \leq 2$ which works for: $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}$
- $g_n(x) = \frac{x}{n} \implies \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x) = 0$ (monotonously)

Therefore the series is uniformly convergent for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Incorrect. Dirichlet test requires partial sums to be bounded, not only the summand.

Comment: To use the Dirichlet test, you need to show that $\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)$ is uniformly bounded for all $n$ and $x$ -- not just boundedness of $f_n(x)$.  Your proof also breaks down for proving uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$ becuase $g_n(x) = x/n$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that $g_n(n) \not\to 0$.

Comment: Then it should work in Abel test, am I right? the series of $\frac{x}{n}$ is convergent for every x and $\frac{sin(n^2x)}{n}$ is monotonous and bounded by 2.

Comment: Of course not. $\sum_n x/n$ is clearly divergent as a multiple of the harmonic series.

Comment: yeah, you are right, but if I put $sin(n^2x)$ alone to get $sum_n x/n^2$ in the sum, then $sin(n^2x)$ is not monotonous and it doesn't work either. Any hint?

Comment: No, just use that $\sum 1/n^2$ converges and $xsin(n^2 x)$ is bounded.

Comment: But $xsin(n^2x) $ is not monotonous when I change $n \to \infty$ and that is required as I suppose (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test).

Comment: The convergence is clearly uniform on any bounded interval by the Weierstrass M-test.  If $|x|\leqslant c$ then $|x \sin( n^2x)/n^2|\leqslant c/n^2$. The harder question is whether or not it converges uniformly for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ... and of course $x \sin(n^2x)$ is not monotone.

Comment: So the idea of @Eric will not work, right?

Comment: Is the first part meant to be a proof that the series is pointwise convergent? It certainly is not enough to show that the terms of the sum tend to $0$. I suggest that comparison with $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ will give (absolute) pointwise convergence.

Comment: I think it's good, but nobody knows how to check uniform convergence so that is the problem.

Comment: @mathbb So with your logic, the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{x}{n}}  = x\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}}$ converges pointwise because $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{x}{n} = 0$, right? In particular, with $x=1$, $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}}$ is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments you can see the issues with your solution. Here I present a possible approach to this problem. The pointwise convergence follows from the estimate
$$
\left| {x\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sin (n^2 x)}}{{n^2 }}} } \right| \le \left| x \right|\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\left| {\sin (n^2 x)} \right|}}{{n^2 }}}  \le \left| x \right|\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}}  = \frac{{\pi ^2 }}{6}\left| x \right|.
$$
Note that
\begin{align*}
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left| {x\sum\limits_{n = 2N}^\infty  {\frac{{\sin (n^2 x)}}{{n^2 }}} } \right| & \ge \left| {\frac{\pi }{2}(2N + 1)\sum\limits_{n = 2N}^\infty  {\frac{{\sin \left( {n^2 \frac{\pi }{2}(2N + 1)} \right)}}{{n^2 }}} } \right|
\\ &
 = \frac{\pi }{2}(2N + 1)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(2N + 2k + 1)^2 }}} \\ &  \ge \frac{\pi }{2}(2N + 1)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(2N + 2k + 1)(2N + 2k + 3)}}} 
\\ &
 = \frac{\pi }{4}(2N + 1)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{{2N + 2k + 1}} - \frac{1}{{2N + 2k + 3}}} \right)}  = \frac{\pi }{4}
\end{align*}
for any positive integer $N$. Thus the series cannot be uniformly convergent.

Comment: Thnak you! Is it possible to check uniform convergence without integrals?

Comment: @mathbb I edited my answer. It uses telescoping sums.

Answer (score 2):

If the series converged uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $2N+1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$\left|\sum_{n= 2N+1}^\infty x \frac{\sin n^2 x}{n^2} \right| < \epsilon$$

In particular, for $x_m = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2m\pi$ we have $\sin n^2x_m = \sin \left( n^2\frac{\pi}{2}+ 2mn^2 \pi\right)= \sin n^2\frac{\pi}{2}$ and

$$\left|\sum_{n= 2N+1}^\infty  \frac{\sin n^2 \frac{\pi}{2}}{n^2} \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2m\pi}$$

Since the RHS converges to $0$ as $m \to \infty$ and the LHS is independent of $m$, we must have

$$\tag{*}\sum_{n= 2N+1}^\infty  \frac{\sin n^2 \frac{\pi}{2}}{n^2}=0$$

However, we can write
$$\sum_{n= 2N+1}^\infty  \frac{\sin n^2 \frac{\pi}{2}}{n^2}= \sum_{j=0}^\infty  \frac{\sin (2N+1+j)^2 \frac{\pi}{2}}{(2N+1+j)^2}$$

where $\sin (2N+1+j)^2 \frac{\pi}{2} = 1$ if $j$ is even and  $\sin (2N+1+j)^2 \frac{\pi}{2} = 0$ if $j$ is odd.

This implies

$$\sum_{n= 2N+1}^\infty  \frac{\sin n^2 \frac{\pi}{2}}{n^2}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{(2N+1+2k)^2} \neq 0,$$

which contradicts (*).